# Is it possible to do a dynamic lookup

Tags: configuration, ansible

I have an environment where the sudo password of a user is not the same on several servers. This can be seen as a security feature :-D

I wanted to save the sudo password (vault/security aside at time point) in a file:

- host1.sudopwd
- host2.sudopwd
- ...
- hostn.sudopwd

in my ansible playbook, I am using something like that:

```
---
- hosts: all
tasks:
- include: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_user: root
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('file','{{ inventory_hostname }}.sudopwd') }}"
```

And it works well if I have one file per hosts.
Now how can I make it more "dynamic"?

Let say that, that I have a script that is called `searchsudopwd`, which is a simple bash script (could be any language in fact).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$1" == "host1" ]]; then
  echo "pwd1"
elif [[ "$1" == "host2" ]]; then
  echo "pwd2"
else
  echo "default pwd"
fi
```

How can I use it with ansible? What needs to be changed in my playbook to make it work?

I have tried something like:

```
---
- hosts: all
tasks:
- include: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_user: root
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ item }}"
    with_lines: searchsudopwd '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
```

But it doesn't work...

If my idea doesn't work, is there a way to have like a "default" password, and only get the password for specific hosts?

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off putting the passwords in the individual host_vars files, when needed, and put the default in group_vars/all.  Put it all in Ansible Vault.  (But then you have a shared password for Ansible Vault.)

I have a host called "ml01" so I changed your script:

```
$ cat /home/jscheible/searchsudopwd
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$1" == "ml01" ]]; then
  echo "pwd1"
elif [[ "$1" == "host2" ]]; then
  echo "pwd2"
else
  echo "default pwd"
fi
```

To call that local program with the passwords, just call that in a play with `delegate_to: localhost`:

```
$ cat show_pwd 
---
- hosts: all
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Do passwd lookup
    command: /home/jscheible/searchsudopwd {{ inventory_hostname }}
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: result

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      var: result.stdout
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Here are the results for my test:

```
$ ansible-playbook show_pwd 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Do passwd lookup] ********************************************************
changed: [al01 -> localhost]
changed: [ml01 -> localhost]

TASK [Show results] ************************************************************
ok: [al01 -> localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "default pwd"
}
ok: [ml01 -> localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "pwd1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you :-) the I didn't know about the "host_vars"! I've tested it and it works as I was expecting!
I didn't check the other part of your answer, but it seems to be "too complicated" compared to the host_vars/group_vars solution

Comment: Once I've enough reputation, I will +1 your answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are handy [lookup plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups).

You can actually just replace your `file` lookup with `pipe` lookup:

```
ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('pipe','/path_on_ansible_machine/searchsudopwd '+inventory_hostname) }}"
```